# Kerberos credential cache type "DIR:"

Tags: linux, security, kerberos

How do I set the MIT Kerberos 5 credential cache type to "DIR:"?

See Release Notes at http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-1.10/

"Major changes in 1.10: Add the DIR credential cache type, which can hold a collection of credential caches."

Unfortunately, I can't find any documentation on how to configure the credential cache type.

Answer (score 0):

check for KRB5CCNAME in `man kerberos`

http://k5wiki.kerberos.org/wiki/Projects/Client_principal_selection

In Fedora/RHEL/Centos this is configured in sssd